# Degree of concurrency of Nodes in graph

Tags: java, graph

how can i determine degree of concurrency of each node in Directed Acycle graph ?
degree of concurency means the number of nodes that can concurenctly run with this node.

Comment: Can you give a more precise definition?

Comment: this is some graph problem what does it have to do with java and programming - you were just asked this assignment question and want the answer = its not acceptable

Comment: i am working in Applications with forms of DAG , and i am scheduling this applications with gridsim and netbeans, one of my methods for test for scheduling  this applications is  calculate Degree of concurrency each nodes (means Task for my works), that means :each task with how number of another tasks can run concurenct, and i need to calculate the degree of concurrency of each task, for example degree of concurrency T1=1,means T1 with another tasks can run concurenctly and i can send concurenctly to a resource.